# (Preferably jQuery) Rich Textbox without any toolbar and just bullets on by Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Hello All and Thanks in Advance

Special Note:
There is no question of why or why not something else. It has to be like this.

I have a problem where I want to let a user input data in a textfield. However the data must be in bulleted format. So as soon as the user presses 'Enter' another bullet starts to enter another row of data.

This data needs to be saved in a database and displayed as well during edit scenario.

Is it possible to use a jQuery plugin. Hide/Remove toolbar. Enable bullets by default so when the control is accessed a bullet appears straight away where user can enter a sentence. Press enter which starts another bullet to enter data and vice versa.

Regards!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question in it.

Comment: If you don’t know how to do a job, perhaps you should figure that out before you accept it.

Comment: "No question of why or why not something else. It has to be like this since the client has asked" - "Needs to be delivered before monday !!!!" , this guy is speaking like we are working for him...

Comment: I think it is a genuine problem. We all know a textbox can be used to enter data however we want. But a textbox that lets user input data in bullets format is a thing that is not available out of the box out there.

Answer (score 1):

This post doesn't have a specific question it seems so I'll tackle the front end aspect of putting borderless textboxes with bullets on the side as well as inserting new ones when pressing enter.

You will have to capture the enter key event when they are focused on the textbox. In order to do this you will need to use code similar to this:

```
$('input[type=text]').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    var input = addInput("");
    $(input).focus();
});

$('input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

For the border-less inputs that will just be CSS to remove the border such as this:

```
.noBorder {
    border: 0px none;
}
```

Just apply that class to your inputs.

Lastly for the bullets you will just need to have a `<ul>` tag and add `<li>` items with the inputs inside.

Here is a working example and I have even wrapped events around textbox changes so you can save to the database: http://jsfiddle.net/cv7L11sn/

Comment: Sam, thanks for the solution. It works fine to an extent but not fully. After few number of new additions, say 2, 3 or 4 may be it stops working. I have been trying to fix the issue but i couldn't. May be you can look into it again and see whats wrong ? And basically it should start with just one bullet by default, Cheers and thanks in advance!